# Rename sym links across filesystems in python

Tags: python, rename

Probably a basic question, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution to it.

I have 2 sym links to 2 directories (s1->d1, s2->d2), which are placed on different filesystems. Is there a way to rename s1 to s2 (that is, s2->d1), in python other than using os.system mv?

`os.rename()` doesn't work across filesystems and `shutil.move()` throws an error saying "Cannot call rmtree on a symbolic link".

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It looks like there was a bug in older versions of `shutil.move()`; see https://bugs.python.org/issue9993

Comment: Ohh! I'm using 2.7.3, and this issue is fixed in 3.3. Not sure if I can upgrade. Seems my only option is os.system